# Как отправить картинку POST запросом NodeJS

Tags: php, node.js

На одном сервере имеется картинка. Как с помощью NodeJS отправить картинку на другой сервер и принять её там с средствами PHP?

Comment: Например, через её base64-код

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15001822/sending-large-image-data-over-http-in-node-js